# An Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio Professional 2015 running a newly created WebAPI 2 project.  I wanted to create a data model from database using entity framework (code first from existing database).  So I downloaded this from oracle.

ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0)

After installation I successfully tested connected to the database using Managed driver, and proceed through the EF wizard.  But at the end I get this error

[image]

I tried both Managed and Unmanaged drivers.  I also tried adding references to these libraries

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
Oracle.ManagedDataAcces.EntityFramework
Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework
Oracle.DataAccess

I check my version of Entity Framework the project is using and it says its using the latest 6.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding this references from Nuget:

- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
- Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework
- Oracle.DataAccess

You have to compile the project in x86 and try again with the wizard. We have had your problem at my office several times, and I think It´s caused because of having the project configured with "any Cpu"

Hope it helps

Comment: This successfully removed that error for me, but now the wizard just crashes out at the same screen. Did you do anything else?

Comment: What we do: Have the lastest update of the Visual studio. Install de EF6 Oracle data tools for Visual Studio (x86). Add the two libraries via Nuget. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Oracle.ManagedDataAcces.EntityFramework Oracle.DataAccess.EntityFramework Oracle.DataAccess. Then configure the application in x86. The last step is to add a new model, and the wizard starts.  If there is a crash, I would suggest to reinstall EF6 Oracle Data tools for Visual Studio